# Force OpenGL to keep contents in memory?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm using OpenGL to render polygons. I notice that if I minimize the program then start using it again, it will be very slow for a few seconds. (I'm guessing its reuploading my display lists to the card). How can I prevent this because it's a bit annoying. I want it to always have the contents.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an OS issue. Does it also happen on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you minimize a program under Windows, it does the equivalent of [`SetProcessWorkingSetSize(current_process, -1,-1);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234%28VS.85%29.aspx). This tells the virtual memory manager that all the memory occupied by that program is eligible for being paged out. The only way I know of to prevent this is to prevent the user from minimizing the program in the first place (e.g., use [`DeleteMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647629%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to remove the "minimize" item from its system menu).

Note that this isn't a matter of your program's drawing data being removed from the graphics card -- it's a matter of all its data (and quite possibly code) being removed from memory entirely. Of course, if you have enough memory and a lightly enough loaded system, it won't be removed immediately -- it's just marked as being available, so if the system needs memory for something else, it will be (some of) the first to get used.